# WordPress - can´t login with the admin account after restoring MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've got a Wordpress blog hosted on Linode under Cherokee web server, but the performance has been problematic the last weeks and I'd like to give a chance to Nginx.

So I've made a DB backup of the current site, setup a LEMP platform, installed wordpress, and the "new" wordpress, with no articles (yet) on it works as expected.

But when I restore the mysql database from the current blog, the site shows a blank page. I've copied all the wp-content directory onto the new WordPress directory, and I've tried to disable all the plugins, but nothing changes.

In fact, there's an even more important problem: **I can't login** with my old admin/pass account, that should be inherited from the old database. In fact when I do a SELECT on the wp_users table, everything seems to be fine (equal to the old installation), but I can't login no matter what I do.

I've even tried to change the admin password with an UPDATE and the MD5 function under mysql, and although the table is updated, the pass does not work either.

So all I get is a restore I can't access

Answer (score 0):

The issue causing the blank page is likely that your old install used a theme other than the default, and since you haven't copied wp-content over, it's looking for a theme that doesn't exist. I find that with importing an installs database, this happens rather than it just reverting to a default theme, as it does when you delete the current theme on an active install.

Something you may consider trying to get around the login problems is doing a WordPress export (Tools -> Export). This will work if you don't have much media attached to your current posts, as it will only copy post contents, and not attachments. Import that export to a fresh WP install on your new platform and both problems should be solved.

Comment: Thanks for the Info Gavin, but 1) As I've said, I've copied the full wp-content directory (themes included) so the theme is there. I think it is more related to some plugin conflict, but anyway, it does not allow to login. 

And 2) The Export could work, but the blog has now over 2.000 posts, 18.000 comments and the XML file generated is huge even without images. I'll try, but I think Wordpress can not handle that big import file.

Comment: Ah sorry, misread RE: uploading wp-content. I find sometimes switching themes back and forth once can help as well, but since you're on a different platform now this may be beyond my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a plugin problem; rename your plugin folder to "oldplugins" and see what happens.

Reupload fresh copies of all WO core files/folders, except for wp-config.php and wp-content

Could be a permissions problem; check http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

And: did you change DB table prefixes?

Comment: Yep, I think I tried that and even renaming the plugin folder I couldn't login with the admin account. As for permissions, I'll have a detailed look at the new system, but the user:group is right and i didn't change permissions after the install... and it has always worked for me. 

In fact, as I said before, the blog works before the database restore, but not after that. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but eventually successfully restored it by trial and error. 
The steps that worked were something like this:

1. uninstalled wordpress
2. installed a version that was working before the upgrade
3. activated same plugins (same version) that were installed before
4. restored the database
5. here's where it gets fuzzy, but had login problems and content would show but no theme, and admin login redirected to root site
6. did this procedure for changing site URL: 
   http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL
7. don't know why that was necessary but after a few minutes, the links started working. And after having to request a new admin login by email several times throughout the process, I was able to admin login again.

Comment: Crow,as I said sometime ago the WP version is the same, because I copied all the folder (including wp-content, with themes, plugins and uploads). Anyway, the problem got solved, but I really don't remember how :(.